# set different times android countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer

So it has been a while since I have tried to program Android. Now I have a better understanding of java than I have in the past, but my question is how can I limit the number of times a button is clicked. The context of this is that I have a timer the timer changes each time the old one has expired. So I have created an Array of times, such as {3,4,7,1,3} but once it hits the end I don't want a toast to pop up. I know how to do the toast part and so right now I have my CountDownTimer(Array[i],0). and in the onFinish method that is provided I index i one more time. But I don't want to call upon this method if i>Array[].lenghth. When I try to add just a simple conditional statement like that before I create a new CountDownTimer, I get an error that involves closing off my methods and conditionals appropriately. Below is what I have. Thank you guys in advance!

```
package com.example.countdown;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int[] Times= new int[];
Times={4,5,3,2,6}
private int index=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        if(index<Times.size()){
        public void onClick(View v){
             CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(
                     Times[i]), 0) {
                    TextView textview =(TextView) findViewById(com.example.countdowntest.R.id.textView);
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {textview.setText("seconds remaining: "
                                + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        textview.setText("done!");
                    index++;
                    }

                }.start();
        }
    });
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `if(index<Times.size()){` inside the `onClick`method

Comment: It works! Thank you, but for some reason, I can't open my app on my AVD. Would that have something to do with the code, the logcat says there was a runTime error in activity thread; and there was no error in installing it. If you have a clue that would help, if not you've already helped out quite a bit for me! Thanks

Comment: You should ask another question for that or modify this one. You can accept this answer if it helped.